# Eloquent Count + Group By + Inner join

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, orm

Estoy teniendo ciertos problemas con las consultas en el ORM-Eloquent, he integrado eloquent en codeigniter, estoy intentando hacer la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT tp.*, COUNT(*) as cuenta
FROM tipo_llamadas tp
INNER JOIN encuestas e ON tp.id = e.id_tipo_llamada
WHERE e.id_oleada = 1
GROUP BY tp.id
```

El resultado es el siguiente:

```
id  | nombre       | cuenta
---------------------------
1   | Información  | 3
2   | Recogida     | 1
```

Pero no logro sacarla, he sacado la siguiente consulta, pero me falta obtener el `INNER JOIN` con `tipo_llamadas` para sacar sus nombres:

```
Encuesta::selectRaw('*, count(*) as cuenta')
           ->groupBy('id_tipo_llamada')
           ->get()
           ->toArray();
```

Comment: En una consulta estás partiendo de `tipo_llamadas` y en la otra de `encuestas`. ¿Es esto correcto según el diseño de tu aplicación?

Comment: Quiero sacar esa misma consulta en mysql con una consulta en eloquent, enucestas tiene un id_tipo_llamada que relaciona a tipo_llamadas.id

Comment: ¿La tabla tipo_llamada está referenciada en algún modelo? Digamos app\Models\TipoLlamada.php

Answer (score 2):

En eloquent dispones de [join( )](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#joins) para hacer inner join

```
Modelo_tipo_llamadas::selectRaw('tipo_llamadas.*, count(*) as cuenta')
            ->join('encuestas e', 'tipo_llamadas.id', '=', 'e.id_tipo_llamada')
            ->where('e.id_oleada', '=', 1)
            ->groupBy('tipo_llamadas.id')
            ->get();
```

Puedes construir también la consulta sin el modelo:

```
$var = DB::table('tipo_llamadas tp')
        ->selectRaw('tp.*, count(*) as cuenta')
        ->join('encuestas e', 'tp.id', '=', 'e.id_tipo_llamada')
        ->where('e.id_oleada', '=', 1)
        ->groupBy('tp.id')
        ->get();
```